# nginx proxy_pass return redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, proxypass

I'm serving my static pages using `nginx`.
I'm trying to proxy requests from `/api` to my backend service.

nginx:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:5000;

  auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
  auth_basic_user_file /.../.htpasswd;

  root /app;
  index index.htm index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass https://api.example.com/;
  }

  location /health {
    auth_basic off;
    return 200;
  }
}
```

Opening the browser and sending a request (from `js`) result in a redirect to `http://localhost:5000/api/`.

curl:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /api HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.0
< Date: Wed, 17 Oct 2018 21:59:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Location: http://localhost:5000/api/
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does `nginx` return a redirect instead of proxy the request to the remote api server?

Comment: Do you have port forwarding 8080 --> 5000 on nginx ? The reason I ask is you are making a request on port 8080 using curl and so was wondering ?

Comment: Yes I do, you can see that I get a response...

Comment: Try curl with `-L` flag to tell it to follow redirects. What you are getting now is as expected. By default, curl does not follow redirects - https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT

Comment: I don't want to be redirected, I want nginx to proxy the request, the nginx was just an example to show the request, but I execute it from JavaScript

Comment: The location block matches the URI `/api/`. You are posting to `/api` without a trailing `/`. Generally, Nginx uses redirect to append `/` to URIs that look like path elements. If you want to proxy `/api` you will need a location or rule that explicitly matches it.